# upload image $_FILES is not set

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file to my server
But the problem is the if(isset($_FILES['upl'])) always returns false

my php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'bmp');
{
    if(isset($_FILES['upl']) )
    {
        echo 'test';
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
            echo json_encode(array('success'=> false, 'message'=> 'No supported file type'));
            exit;
        }


    $filename = "test".$extension;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $url.'images/uploads/'.$filename)){
        echo json_encode(array('success'=> true, 'url'=> $weburl .'images/uploads/'. $filename, 'filename' => $_FILES['upl']['name']));
        exit;
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
                            <label for="file">Logo</label><input type="file" name="upl">
                            <input type="submit" disabled='disabled' value=''>
                        </form>
```

I never use an action if inpage check, using one doesn't fix the problem

Comment: `isset($_FILES['file']['upl'])`

Answer (score 9):

You are missing

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in the form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

`<form action="" method="post">`

to

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `enctype` in the `form`.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Logo</label>
    <input type="file" name="upl" />
    <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add the attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag to upload the file into server....

Answer (score 2):

Very important attribute when uploading files is the `enctype`:

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 2):

For file upload, you need to add attribute:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

So, your updated code should be:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed enctype parameter in your from attributes. ***Its not necessary if you used GET method*** for file uploading. But if you used POST method for file uploading then, your form parameter should be like this,

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```